# FTP сервер возвращает ошибку 227

Tags: c#, ftp

Доброго времени суток. Собственно, сабж в титле.

Сама ошибка выглядит по меньшей мере непонятно:

> "Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: 227 Entering Passive Mode
>   (192,168,1,136,39,43)"

при чём тут ошибка? мне же и нужно в пассивный режим зайти... ладно, едем дальше.

Опыта работы с ftp нет, нашел какие то исходники, собрал проект, выдаётся вышеупомянутое исключение. Упростил код до невозможности, ошибка осталась. Странность ещё в том, что в totalCommander соединение удаётся,

```
    private void btn_connect_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FtpWebRequest requestDir = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://192.168.1.136/");
        requestDir.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        requestDir.Method = "LIST";
        requestDir.UseBinary = true;
        requestDir.EnableSsl = false;
        requestDir.UsePassive = true;

        try
        {
            WebResponse response = requestDir.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString() + ": \n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

пробовал так же ставить

> requestDir.UsePassive = false;

Получил ошибку 500, синтаксическую, мол, команда не опознана.
Буду благодарен, если мне объяснят, что я делаю не так)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Задайте

```
requestDir.UsePassive = false;
```

Далее, в чем возможно заключается сама ошибка и почему сервер возвращает ошибку 500.

Дело в том что Вы задали команду вывода списка файлов:

```
requestDir.Method = "LIST";
```

Попробуйте сначала вывести список директорий:

```
requestDir.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
```

или так:

```
requestDir.Method = "NLST";
```

Список предустановленных команд `FTP` в `.NET`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Спасибо, но проблемы это не решило =) Попробовал работать с командой "NLST". Что в пассивном, что в активном режиме ошибки остались те-же (227 и 500 соответственно). Я уже думал грешить на сам FTP сервер, но стандартные средства Windows и TotalCommander подключаются без проблем.

Answer (score 1):

Без костылей решить не удалось.

Банально скачал левую dll для работы с [FTP](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread1772932.html#post9340312) (сам тут человек новый, так что ссыль на Cyberforum, где первоначально задавал вопрос, как залить архив - не увидел))).

Далее работал так:

```
    FTP _ftp;

        private void btn_Connect_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _ftp = new FTP(); 
            _ftp.TransferCompleteEvent += new FTP.TransferCompleteEventHandler(ftp_TransferCompleted);

            _ftp.HostAddress = "192.168.1.136";
            _ftp.UserName = "username";
            _ftp.Password = "password";
            _ftp.Port = 21;
            _ftp.UseBinary = true;
            _ftp.OverwriteFiles = true;
            _ftp.OverwriteReadOnlyFiles = false;
            _ftp.EnableSSL = false;
            _ftp.UsePassive = true;

            _ftp.Connect();

             string localPath = new FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName;
             _ftp.CurrentDirectory = @"";
             _ftp.DownloadDirectoryAsync(localPath, @"datalog"); 
} 

private void ftp_TransferCompleted(Object sender, TransferCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            _ftp.Disconnect();

             //...
        }
```